# ffmpeg avcodec_open2 changed audio format in AVCodecContext

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

I have a mkv file with a DTS track.

After avcodec_open2 is called, sample_fmt in AVCodexContext changed. Is it expected?

```
AVCodecContext* avAudioCodecCtx = avFormatCtx->streams[audioStreamIndex]->codec;

AVSampleFormat f = avAudioCodecCtx->sample_fmt; // AV_SAMPLE_FMT_FLTP
avcodec_open2(avAudioCodecCtx, avAudioCodec, NULL);
AVSampleFormat f2 = avAudioCodecCtx->sample_fmt; // AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S32P
```

ffprobe

```
ffprobe version N-79143-g8ff0f6a Copyright (c) 2007-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.3.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libdcadec --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmfx --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-decklink --enable-zlib
  libavutil      55. 19.100 / 55. 19.100
  libavcodec     57. 30.100 / 57. 30.100
  libavformat    57. 29.101 / 57. 29.101
  libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
  libavfilter     6. 40.102 /  6. 40.102
  libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
  libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100

Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: dts (DTS), 48000 Hz, 5.1(side), fltp, 768 kb/s (default)
```

Decoding

```
avcodec_decode_audio4(avAudioCodecCtx, frame, &frameComplete, avPacket);
frame->format // contains AV_SAMPLE_FMT_FLTP
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is expected. So, this may be slightly annoying, but `avcodec_open2()` simply sets `sample_fmt` to the "most likely" format given the information stored in the `AVCodecContext` when opening the codec. For some formats, all this information is in the bitstream packets, so they just don't know.

The *actual* format is set in `AVFrame->format` for each decoded packet (or `AVCodecContext->sample_fmt` after decoding the packet). This is typically constant across the whole stream, but this is not guaranteed. The reason that the format is identical to the one in `AVCodecContext->format` *before* calling `avcodec_open2()` is that the demuxer (or, more specifically, `avformat_find_stream_info()`) may open the decoder and try decoding a frame; when that happens, `AVCodecContext->sample_fmt` is set to the same value as `AVFrame->format`, but this value is overwritten again when you call `avcodec_open2()` to start actual bitstream decoding...

Conclusion: use `AVCodecContext->sample_fmt` as informational, and rely on `AVFrame->format` for any practical uses.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. Does this mean, instead of just having one SwrContext per audio stream, I have to create new SwrContext for each frame with its format as input format for swr_convert?

Comment: Only if the format changes. Although it is - for some codecs - possible that it changes per frame, this should be considered highly unusual, and thus caching of these contexts should be done to improve performance for the common case.